# how to get rid of Instance of 'Future<dynamic>' in Flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

main(){
  var list = logic();
  removeOne(list);
}


logic() async{
  final result = await http.get('https://invidio.us/api/v1/search?q=tech+lead');
  final data = json.decode(result.body);
  final myList = [];
  data.forEach((e) {    
    myList.add({"title": e['title'], 'videoId': e['videoId'], 'duration': e['lengthSeconds'], "date": e['publishedText']});
    print(myList);
  });
  return myList;
}

removeOne(aList){
  aList.removeLast();
  print(aList);
}
```

When I run it I get the following error.

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method 'removeLast'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: removeLast()
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      removeOne (file:///Users/macpro/Desktop/minimaltube/logic.dart:23:9)
#2      main (file:///Users/macpro/Desktop/minimaltube/logic.dart:7:3)
#3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:19)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

How do I get rid of `var list` being a `'Future<dynamic>'`? I want it to become a var so I can have access to it later on so `removeOne(list)` can do its job.

Comment: ```var list = await logic();```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The future has not been resolved and must be resolved first so that you can use the returned data as a list.

The compiler goes step by step in your main method, and before the future has been resolved (still a future), it is assigned to the variable list, then moves to next line when we pass that future to the function "removeOne(list)".

What you can do to resolve your future is, add a .then() after the function call so it waits for the future and when it comes, converts it to the data type that you want.

Replace the code in your main as follows:

```
logic().then((list) => removeOne(list));
```

Or, you can go with another approach of having your complete main method async, which is controversial and some say its not a good practice. That would be as follows:

```
main() async {
 var list = await logic();
 removeOne(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
main() async {

List<String> list = await logic<String>();
removeOne(list);

}


Future<List<T>>logic<T>() async{
      final result = await http.get('https://invidio.us/api/v1/search?q=tech+lead');
      final data = json.decode(result.body);
      final myList = [];
      data.forEach((e) {    
      myList.add({"title": e['title'], 'videoId': e['videoId'], 'duration': 
      e['lengthSeconds'], "date": e['publishedText']});
      print(myList);
  });
 return myList;
}

removeOne(aList){
  aList.removeLast();
  print(aList);
}
```